# backbone.js alternatives that plays ball with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Are there any alternatives to something like backbone.js out there that provides some framework/structure to your front end javascript - but don't have any unwanted dependencies and are more closely married to jQuery?

Comment: Backbone has "unwanted dependencies" ? How could you _not_ want underscore? It's the _best_ library ever. P.S. tight coupling to jQuery sounds really painful to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you asking for an easy to use MVC framework?
because [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) seems to be by far the most easy RESTful framework with routes, managing hash changes, and templating plugins.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted, but Sammy.js looks pretty awesome and I've never heard about it before. I'm also using mustache, so it seems like a match made in heaven.

Answer (score 5):

have you checked [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/)

also [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that sproutCore is so much more than a javascript framework/MVC. It's way to big for my tastes

Comment: was the negative necessary? anyway I added another suggestion

Comment: I am a big fan of JavaScriptMVC. Not exactly lightweight, but a very powerful but if kit. Particularly useful for production builds and automated testing.

Comment: in the last few months I have been heavily involved in development using exclusively KnockoutJS, the framework has excellent tutorials and it is gaining speed as far as adoption, new version 1.3 is about to be released, http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 3):

## Spine

I think there's only one MVC framework that is as fully featured and still even more puristic and that's Spine [http://spinejs.com/](http://spinejs.com). It's not so closely married to jQuery though since it's actually not dependent on any other library.

### Spine vs. Backbone

The fundamental difference between Backbone is that Spine wants to abstract the server away completely so that none of the asynchronous calls are being waited, but that the application just continues it's work while the calls are done in the background. (http://spinejs.com/docs/introduction)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend everyone to have a look at [ember.js](http://emberjs.com).

Ember is much more of a high level framework with many useful features implemented implemented out of the box. For example:

- Two way data binding
- Computed properties
- Auto-updating templates

On the other hand the fact that is higher level than Backbone makes it less flexible , thus less attractive for those javascript developers that like tweaking the system and getting their hands dirty.

For those interested you can find a great comparison between the two at: http://smus.com/backbone-and-ember/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few days old now, as well as a shameless plug - but I am the author of [AFrameJS](http://www.aframejs.com), which plays well with jQuery.  There are a lot of docs there, also some on [shanetomlinson.com](http://www.shanetomlinson.com).  The source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/stomlinson/AFrame-JS).  K Ivanov already mentioned [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/), and then there is [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/).  [Ext](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/), is a library that would replace jQuery, but is also an MVC library that contains a ton of pre-built widgets.  There are a ton to choose from - a very good thing.

Comment: I had forgotten about knockout. To me, ext.js is doing way too much. I had a look at AFrameJS (btw horrible name :) but it looks interesting because it doesn't seem to do "too much"

Comment: A horrible name yes, but I dig it.  :D

Answer (score 0):

current version of backbone.js seems to work with [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) library

it's a lightweight alternative to jquery (it's less that a quarter jquery's size)