# observable pattern on client side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any work around for client side data binding in mvc. I'm looking for something like implementing a observable pattern on client side somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [knockout](http://www.knockoutjs.com) it might provide something like what you are after

From their site

> **Declarative Bindings** Easily associate DOM elements with model data using a concise, readable syntax
>
> **Automatic UI Refresh** When your data model's state changes, your UI updates automatically
>
> **Dependency Tracking** Implicitly set up chains of relationships between model data, to transform and combine it
>
> **Templating** Quickly generate sophisticated, nested UIs as a function of your model data

Also

> Knockout is a JavaScript library that helps you to create rich,
>   responsive display and editor user interfaces with a clean underlying
>   data model. Any time you have sections of UI that update dynamically
>   (e.g., changing depending on the user’s actions or when an external
>   data source changes), KO can help you implement it more simply and
>   maintainably.
>
> **Headline features**:
>
> Elegant dependency tracking - automatically updates the right parts of
>   your UI whenever your data model changes. Declarative bindings - a
>   simple and obvious way to connect parts of your UI to your data model.
>   You can construct a complex dynamic UIs easily using arbitrarily
>   nested binding contexts. Trivially extensible - implement custom
>   behaviors as new declarative bindings for easy reuse in just a few
>   lines of code.

In order to prevent some of the additional work in creating viewmodels if you already have JSON objects being returned to the client you could use the [Knockout Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

> Knockout is designed to allow you to use arbitrary JavaScript objects
>   as view models. As long as some of your view model’s properties are
>   observables, you can use KO to bind to them to your UI, and the UI
>   will be updated automatically whenever the observable properties
>   change.
>
> Most applications need to fetch data from a backend server. Since the
>   server doesn’t have any concept of observables, it will just supply a
>   plain JavaScript object (usually serialized as JSON). The mapping
>   plugin gives you a straightforward way to map that plain JavaScript
>   object into a view model with the appropriate observables. This is an
>   alternative to manually writing your own JavaScript code that
>   constructs a view model based on some data you’ve fetched from the
>   server.

There are also other frameworks that do similar things like:

- [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [More alternatives here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882184/backbone-js-alternatives-that-plays-ball-with-jquery)

If you want to implement it without using a "big" framework maybe take a look at this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005300/example-of-javascript-observer-pattern

Comment: thanks for the link i had it before problem is it involves too much javascript at client side. but I'll keep it as the last option. so just wondering is there anything other solution available?

Comment: any client side solution is going to involve javascript

Comment: have you watched the introduction video on the site, I would argue it actually involves less javascript, you just have to know how it works (by reading the docs)

Comment: I have tried its interact sessions once. The only problem i find with it is that it requires me to manage viewmodel at the client side. In asp.net mvc I already have model available at client side but if i go down this road i'll need to add an extra layer for viewmodel and manage it myself. so just want to make sure if thats the only way to do it or are there other options available

Comment: have you seen the mapping plugin knockout has, updated answer to reflect

Comment: Note - knockout is powerful but it also requires you do client side binding. Theres nothing really integrated yet for your server side/mvc model validation unless you are using unobtrusive and solely rely on that.